# choose scale of x values in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a histogram using matplotlib. my X values double, from 2 - 2048. When I graph this on a histogram, there are a bunch of values right next to each other at the start, then it spreads out as the values go up. Since I know I will not have values in between, How can I change the graph to it steps up by a multiple of two? I have tried `from matplotlib.pyplot import xticks` but that only changes what is displayed.

```
import matplotlib
from numpy.random import randn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
import random
from matplotlib.pyplot import xticks


def to_percent(y, position):
    # Ignore the passed in position. This has the effect of scaling the default
    # tick locations.
    s = str(100 * y)

    # The percent symbol needs escaping in latex
    if matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] is True:
        return s + r'$\%$'
    else:
        return s + '%'
z = [2, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048]
x = [z[random.randint(0, 6)] for i in range(100)]
xticks(z)
plt.xscale('log')
# Make a normed histogram. It'll be multiplied by 100 later.
plt.hist(x, bins=50, normed=True)


# Create the formatter using the function to_percent. This multiplies all the
# default labels by 100, making them all percentages
formatter = FuncFormatter(to_percent)

# Set the formatter
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just plot the log values, and the log of the formatters. It is *much* simpler ...

```
plt.hist(np.log(x), bins=50, normed=True)
plt.xticks(np.log(z), z)
```

You can also use a base 2 log if you wish ...

Comment: Remember ... `import numpy as np`

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Seems I know have an issue with my percentages

Comment: Im not exactly sure that `normed` does. Maybe its that.